# Is there a well supported feed generation library for Java?

Tags: java, rss, atom-feed

I'm looking to build a feed generator for RSS and Atom feeds.

I've been looking around for a library that will generate a wide variety of formats (RSS .9 through whatever is current, and Atom .3 through whatever is current).

I'd rather not look through the specs and try recreating the wheel, but the libraries I've found so far for generating feeds are either not very robust (only support a specific format/version) or look to be poorly supported or abandoned projects.

Is there a good library out there?

Answer (score 4):

RSS is just an XML file! So you can use every XML writer out there. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html) is an example using "Java Stax XML".
At point 5 you see the creation of an example xml file, showing you the correct syntax of a valid RSS feed file.

Comment: Yeah.  I was kind of hoping not to have to look into the standards for each format but I think that's what I'm relegated to.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [Apache Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org/) is new and supported.

> The goal of the Apache Abdera project is to build a functionally-complete, high-performance implementation of the IETF Atom Syndication Format (RFC 4287) and Atom Publishing Protocol (RFC 5023) specifications.

In past [ROME](http://rometools.github.io/rome/) was popular, but doesn't look like there have been anything released recently.

Comment: Does it support RSS or its only for atom?

Comment: Btw, whereas Apache Abdera seems dead since 2012, ROME is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

Trye feed4j. feed4j is a feed parser library for the Java 2 platform

Comment: Thanks, but that's a parser - I'm looking to create feeds that would be consumed by this kind of library.